# Where can I find PostGIS error codes?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Using `ST_Contains` in `where` clause sometimes gives me error messages like

`ERROR:  GEOSContains: TopologyException: side location conflict at 37.3706 55.7882`

For now I can't guarantee validity for every geometry in DB, using third-party import tools, so I just catch every exception:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION safe_st_contains(geom1 geometry, geom2 geometry)
  RETURNS BOOL AS
  $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN ST_Contains($1, $2);
    EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'TopologyException'; -- this is a guess
      RETURN FALSE;
  END;
  $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'd like to know where exceptions like TopologyException really belong and which exception conditions should I use instead of `OTHERS` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can reproduce the error, you can get the exact error code yourself pretty easily:

```
DO $$
  BEGIN
    PERFORM ST_Contains('problem 1 geom here'::GEOMETRY, 'problem geom 2 here'::GEOMETRY);
    EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'Error code: %', SQLSTATE;
      RAISE NOTICE 'Error message: %', SQLERRM;
  END;
$$
```

(Put your actual geometries in, of course.)

Running this will print out the code and the error message.

I wasn't doing `ST_Contains`, but as an example, I got this result from a particular `TopologyException` I'm running into:

```
Error code: XX000
Error message: GEOSUnaryUnion: TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING (401336 4.79544e+06, 401336 4.79544e+06) and LINESTRING (401336 4.79544e+06, 401339 4.79543e+06) at 401336.24785627011 4795435.9978510197
```

The PostgreSQL [error codes list](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/errcodes-appendix.html) says that `XX000` is "internal_error". My best guess is that this is just the code PostgreSQL uses when random, third party native code blows up, since PostgreSQL can't do all that much with those errors. Might be worth getting on the PostGIS mailing list and seeing if they can do something to at least give general PostGIS errors a more specific code.

Answer (score 2):

Best I could find by briefly looking at the PostGIS code was, that these kind of exceptions are raised by GEOS. So I would recommend you to look at their wiki, sources etc. like http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/wiki/TopologyExceptions

Comment: Here's how you can [search the source for "TopologyException"](https://github.com/libgeos/libgeos/search?q=TopologyException)